# Adding a multiple space character's in nodejs using replace method

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, replace

I have the following variable.

```
var s = 'Hi Al !'
```

Which i would like to convert to

```
'Hi    Al !'
```

I.E. basically add 4 space characters and hence taught i could do the following:-

```
var new_var = s.replace('Hi', 'Hi\s\s\s\s');
```

But the above only gives me the output `Hissss Al !`, which is not what i want. How do i add 4 space characters to my string ?

I have also tried `var new_var = s.replace('Hi', 'Hi\t');`

But the output has about 6-7 spaces.

Comment: Doesn't a simple ` ` solve your problem?

Comment: Just add space, not \s

Answer (score 3):

Just use the space character:

```js
var s = 'Hi Al !'
var new_var = s.replace('Hi', 'Hi    ');
console.log(new_var)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `\s` matches a whitespace char using a regular expression. If you use that in the replacement, it will just be `s`

If there is a variable number of spaces after Hi, and you want to change that to always have 4 spaces, you can match 1 or more whitespace chars and use 4 spaces in the replacement.

```js
var s = 'Hi              Al !';
var new_var = s.replace(/Hi\s+/, 'Hi    ');
console.log(new_var)
```